# Convert Word Document to PDF using Java

Tags: java, file-conversion

I want to convert ms word document to PDF file using POI.jar(read the MS word Content) and Itext.jar(Creat the PDF File).

For Plain text in MS word, I am able to conver into PDF. But I have few images on ms word. I want to put those images on PDF.

Could some please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You lucky man i just stumbled upon [JODConverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) it uses openoffice to covert through java and its very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a solution for free, you will have to buy something like [Aspose components](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.total-for-java/default.aspx), but you can also save the Word document as HTML and use any of the available HTML-to-PDF tools to convert it to PDF using Java. One of them is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).